# How to write function without using async/await?

Tags: express, vue.js, async-await

I have the function below from: https://github.com/anaida07/MEVN-boilerplate/blob/master/client/src/components/EditPost.vue

```
methods: {
  async getPost () {
    const response = await PostsService.getPost({
      id: this.$route.params.id
    })
    this.title = response.data.title
    this.description = response.data.description
  // this.$router.push({ name: 'Posts' })
},
```

I am learning about MEVN. I wanted to know if there was anyway to write the same function without using async/await. I currently have come up with the following:

```
methods: {
  getPost () {
    const response = PostsService
    .getPost({
      id: this.$route.params.id
    })
    this.title = response.data.title
    this.description = response.data.description

   //this.$router.push({ name: 'Posts' })
},
```

But I am getting an error in my console log saying: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: response.data is undefined". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the a reason why you don't want `async-await` syntax?

Comment: it doesn't work with my version of webpack for some reason

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `PostsService` extends axios, so you can use it as a promise:

```
methods: {
  getPost () {
    PostsService
      .getPost({
        id: this.$route.params.id
      })
      .then(({data}) => {
        this.title = data.title
        this.description = data.description
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Posts' })
      }

},
```

The reason for your error was that `response = PostsService.getPosts()` doesn't actually populate the response variable with the data.  It has to run the query first, then you can access it in the callback in `.then()`

Comment: I agree with Jeff. The `response` is undefined since the `PostsService.getPost()` is an asynchronous request and you will have to wait for it to resolve (or reject) before accessing the response contents. 
For the errors thrown by this request, you can just catch them using a `catch()` block after the `then()` case.

Comment: Thank you, this was a quick fix!